# How to return an empty Observable but continue streaming

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to create a function:

```
 public get test(): Observable<Array<object>> {
   this.http.get<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/home/`)
.subscribe((data: Observable<Object>) => {
  return data;  // actual data
});
return of([{}]);
```

The idea is to subscribe to this function and get actual data when it's available. Something like this:

```
 this.dataSvc.test.subscribe(data => {
  this.data = data;
});
```

I am getting empty data a couple of times but never the real one. However, I am getting to the line marked as "actual data".

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Update.
my HTML:

```
h3><span class="badge badge-primary">{{data[name]}}: </span></h3>
h3><span class="badge badge-primary">{{data[dataid]}}</span>/h3>
```

Comment: why don't you just return the observable
  

`public get test(): Observable<Array<object>> {
   return this.http.get<any>('${environment.apiUrl}/api/home/')
}`

Comment: Do NOT subscribe in the service. Just return the observable.

Comment: wirite return in `get test()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
public get test(): Observable<Array<object>> {
  return this.http.get<Array<object>>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/home/`);
}

 this.dataSvc.test.subscribe(data => {
  this.data = data;
});
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Just want to ask this. Why the line this.data = data; gets hit multiple times with the same result?

Comment: @Mark bcs here we are creating a getter for the same thats why so if you want response only one time then remove the `get` keyword before the `test()`

Comment: If I remove get then I get this error when compiling: error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() => Observable<object[]>'. at the line: this.dataSvc.test.subscribe

Comment: you need to do subscribe like this `this.dataSvc.test().subscribe(data => {
  this.data = data;
}); write `()` after the test
`

Comment: are you calling any function from `html` directly?

Comment: Not sure. I am updating my question with markup sample.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203739/discussion-between-yash-rami-and-mark).